# load dll from python

Tags: python, swig, scons, dynamic-linking

I'm building a python application from some source code I've found [Here](http://code.google.com/p/enso)

I've managed to compile and fix some problems by searching the web, but I'm stuck at this point:

When running the application this message appears.

[alt text http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/4481/loadfr0.png](http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/4481/loadfr0.png)

This python app, usues swig to link to c/c++ code.

I have VC++2005 express edition which I used to compile along with scons
and Python 2.5 ( and tried 2.4 too )

The dlls that are attempting to load is "msvcr80.dll"  because before the message was "msvcr80.dll" cannot be found or something like that, so I got it and drop it in window32 folder.

For what I've read in here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591(VS.80).aspx

The solution is to run MT with the manifest and the dll file. I did it already and doesn't work either.

Could anyone point me to the correct direction?

This is the content of the manifest fie:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

I'm going to try Python 2.6 now, I'm not quite sure of understanding the problem, but Python 2.5 and Python 2.5 .exe had the string "MSVCR71.dll" inside the .exe file. But probably this has nothing to do.

ps. if only  everything was as easy as jar files :(

This is the stack trace for completeness

```
None
INFO:root:Skipping provider enso.platform.osx.
INFO:root:Skipping provider enso.platform.linux.
INFO:root:Added provider enso.platform.win32.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts\run_enso.py", line 24, in <module>
    enso.run()
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\__init__.py", line 40, in run
    from enso.events import EventManager
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\events.py", line 60, in <module>
    from enso import input
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\input\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    _input = enso.providers.getInterface( "input" )
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\providers.py", line 137, in getInterface
    interface = provider.provideInterface( name )
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\platform\win32\__init__.py", line 48, in provideInterface
    import enso.platform.win32.input
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\platform\win32\input\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from InputManager import *
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-read-only\enso\platform\win32\input\InputManager.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _InputManager
ImportError: DLL load failed: Error en una rutina de inicializaci¾n de biblioteca de vÝnculos dinßmicos (DLL).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to compile and run Enso by using /LD as a compiler flag.  This links dynamically to the MS Visual C++ runtime, and seems to allow you to get away without a manifest.

If you're using SCons, see the diff file here: http://paste2.org/p/69732

Comment: Hey Spike, I feel like I know you :P I've been chasing your comments in Enso groups but the format doesn't helpt too much.  Yeap, I follow that link and was able to do most of the work until here.

Comment: The problem ( i guess because this is my 2nd day with C++ ) is python2.5 and VS C++ 2005 have different vscrt(xx).dll The first uses 71 and the former 80. So now I've downloaded python2.6 and VS2008, they both use vscrt90.dll. But now I'm stock with :
ImportError: DLL load failed:.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your update, it looks like you need to install [Pycairo](http://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/) since you're missing the _cairo module installed as part of Pycairo. See the [Pycairo downloads page](http://www.cairographics.org/download/) for instructions on how to obtain/install binaries for Windows.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the VC++ runtime redistributables. The links to them are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99479/visual-cstudio-application-configuration-incorrect#100310).

Answer (score 0):

**update**
I've downloaded python2.6 and VS C++ express edition 2008 and the problem with the msvcr80.dll is gone ( I assume because Python and VSC++2008xe use msvscr90.dll)

I've compile with /LD and all the changes listed here: http://paste2.org/p/69732

And now the problem follows:

```
INFO:root:Skipping provider enso.platform.osx.
INFO:root:Skipping provider enso.platform.linux.
INFO:root:Added provider enso.platform.win32.
INFO:root:Obtained interface 'input' from provider 'enso.platform.win32'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts\run_enso.py", line 23, in <module>
    enso.run()
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\__init__.py", line 41, in run
    from enso.quasimode import Quasimode
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\quasimode\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from enso.quasimode.window import TheQuasimodeWindow
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\quasimode\window.py", line 65, in <module>
    from enso.quasimode.linewindows import TextWindow
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\quasimode\linewindows.py", line 44, in <module>
    from enso import cairo
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\cairo.py", line 3, in <module>
    __cairoImpl = enso.providers.getInterface( "cairo" )
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\providers.py", line 137, in getInterface
    interface = provider.provideInterface( name )
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\platform\win32\__init__.py", line 61, in provideInterface
    import enso.platform.win32.cairo
  File "C:\oreyes\apps\enso\enso-comunity\enso\platform\win32\cairo\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _cairo import *
ImportError: No module named _cairo
```