# how to make distributable C++ programs in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The programs made in visual studio do not run on machines that don't have visual studio
I have searched over the internet for this but found nothing helpful
I'm new to programming and I can't make pure win32 apps rather I can only make console win 32 apps

Can anybody tell me how can I make my programs distributable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't they run? If you're getting "application configuration incorrect" errors, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99479/visual-c-studio-application-configuration-incorrect

Comment: Depending on what sort of machines you are installing on, you may need to also install the Visual Studio redistributable package for the particular VS version and platform you are using.

Comment: Depending on how complex your code is, you may try to rebuild with some other compiler like the old Borland stack. Of course, this much better works for console applications and non-GUI DLLs

Comment: if you are going cross-platform VS it's not exactly a good choice, I also think that VS it's a tool that is just really ugly and cumbersome for serious development. I suggest qtCreator which is a good generic C++ IDE. Even better adopting Cmake, make and mingw/gcc.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the machines where the program fails to run are missing the appropriate C/C++ runtime runtime.

You have two main options.

1. Deploy the appropriate redistributable package for your version of Visual Studio. This is needed when you link to the runtime dynamically.
2. Link to the runtime statically. That way the runtime is built into your executable.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is meant by linking runtime dynamically or statically

Comment: Dynamic linking of the runtime means linking against DLLs that are located and loaded at load time. Statically linking means building the runtime code into your program. So it doesn't have to be separately deployed.